# How to write the below code better to avoid "Apex CPU time limit exceeded" error?

Tags: apex

Here is the code, Its doing something pretty simple.
Find the students that have the grade as WP,WF,WN. Count it for each student and update it.

The below code was working fine in dev and test, but I guess prod had way too many students and it hit the error.

```
global class Add_WP_WF_WN_Grade_To_Program_Enrollment implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
      List<hed__Course_Enrollment__c> courseConnection_WP_WF_WN_Grade = [SELECT hed__Program_Enrollment__r.Id  FROM hed__Course_Enrollment__c WHERE (Letter_Grade__c = 'WP' AND hed__Course_Offering__r.hed__Course__r.Course_Type__c = 'something') OR (Letter_Grade__c = 'WN' AND hed__Course_Offering__r.hed__Course__r.Course_Type__c = 'something') OR (Letter_Grade__c = 'WF' AND hed__Course_Offering__r.hed__Course__r.Course_Type__c = 'something')   ];
        
        Map<String, Integer> grade_WP_WF_WN_Map = new Map<String, Integer>();
        String key;
        for(hed__Course_Enrollment__c u_id: courseConnection_WP_WF_WN_Grade ){
            system.debug(u_id.hed__Program_Enrollment__r.Id);
            
            key = u_id.hed__Program_Enrollment__r.Id;
            if(!grade_WP_WF_WN_Map.containsKey(key)) {
                grade_WP_WF_WN_Map.put(key,0 );
            }
            grade_WP_WF_WN_Map.put(key,grade_WP_WF_WN_Map.get(key) + 1 );
        }
        
      
        
        Set<String> programEnrollmentId = new Set<String>();
        for(String key2: grade_WP_WF_WN_Map.keySet() ) {
            programEnrollmentId.add(key2);
        }
        
        List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c> listOfProgramEnrollmentWithGrade_WP_WF_WN = [SELECT Name,Id,Total_Withdraws__c  FROM hed__Program_Enrollment__c WHERE Id =:programEnrollmentId];
        List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c> listOfProgramEnrollmentToUpdate = new List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c>();
        
        for(hed__Program_Enrollment__c pe_u: listOfProgramEnrollmentWithGrade_WP_WF_WN){
            for(String key3: grade_WP_WF_WN_Map.keySet()){
                if(key3 == pe_u.Id){
                    hed__Program_Enrollment__c updatePE = pe_u;
                    updatePE.Total_Withdraws__c = grade_WP_WF_WN_Map.get(key3);
                    listOfProgramEnrollmentToUpdate.add(updatePE);
                }
            }
        }
        
        update listOfProgramEnrollmentToUpdate;
        
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a map, you just need to get the value out of the map:

```
for(hed__Program_Enrollment__c pe_u: listOfProgramEnrollmentWithGrade_WP_WF_WN){
    pe_u.Total_Withdraws__c = grade_WP_WF_WN_Map.get(pe_u.Id);
    listOfProgramEnrollmentToUpdate.add(pe_u);
}
```

You also don't even need to *copy* the records, just use the original list:

```
List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c> listOfProgramEnrollmentWithGrade_WP_WF_WN = [SELECT Name,Id,Total_Withdraws__c  FROM hed__Program_Enrollment__c WHERE Id =:programEnrollmentId];
for(hed__Program_Enrollment__c pe_u: listOfProgramEnrollmentWithGrade_WP_WF_WN){
    pe_u.Total_Withdraws__c = grade_WP_WF_WN_Map.get(pe_u.Id);
}
update listOfProgramEnrollmentWithGrade_WP_WF_WN;
```

You can also skip a containsKey check for better performance.

In addition, you can use `__c` instead of `__r.Id` for better performance.

Here's the final revision of optimizations:

```
global class Add_WP_WF_WN_Grade_To_Program_Enrollment implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
      List<hed__Course_Enrollment__c> courseConnection_WP_WF_WN_Grade = [SELECT hed__Program_Enrollment__c  FROM hed__Course_Enrollment__c WHERE Letter_Grade__c IN ('WP','WN','WF') AND hed__Course_Offering__r.hed__Course__r.Course_Type__c = 'something'   ];
        Map<Id, Integer> grade_WP_WF_WN_Map = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        for(hed__Course_Enrollment__c u_id: courseConnection_WP_WF_WN_Grade ){
            Id key = u_id.hed__Program_Enrollment__c;
            Integer value = grade_WP_WF_WN_Map.get(key);
            if(value == null) {
                value = 0;
            }
            grade_WP_WF_WN_Map.put(key,value + 1 );
        }
        List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c> listOfProgramEnrollmentWithGrade_WP_WF_WN = [SELECT Name,Id,Total_Withdraws__c  FROM hed__Program_Enrollment__c WHERE Id =:grade_WP_WF_WN_Map.keySet()];
        for(hed__Program_Enrollment__c pe_u: listOfProgramEnrollmentWithGrade_WP_WF_WN){
            pe_u.Total_Withdraws__c = grade_WP_WF_WN_Map.get(pe_u.Id);
        }
        update listOfProgramEnrollmentWithGrade_WP_WF_WN;
    }
}
```

Comment: My only other point would be to ask why this is global and whether it really needs to be.

Comment: Its has to be global because its a 'schedulable' class. It one of the conditions

Comment: @sfdcfox, could my first query be better ? 'something' is the same value throughout the query.

Comment: @manb Bachable classes may be public, no need to be global unless in a managed package and intended to be executed by subscriber. And yes, you can reduce the filter to just `WHERE Letter_Grade__c IN ('WP','WN','WF') AND hed__Course_Offering__r.hed__Course__r.Course_Type__c = 'something'`. Using the IN operator makes it far less complicated.

Comment: And does take query take less processing time too ?

Comment: @manb Nope. The query optimizer should make it just as efficient either way. It's just much less code.

Comment: Got it. And thank you so much @sfdcfox. I've been thrown into a salesforce project with zero prior experience. You have helped me a great deal over the past 2 months. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: @manb You're welcome!